# Create two paragraphs within an article HTML5

Tags: css, html, parallax, paragraphs

I am quite new with HTML5. Now I'm trying two make to paragraphs in the first article. I used some snippets of http://f6design.com/projects/parallax-scrolling/. Simply I want to achieve two paragraphs on the intro article. I tried this alternative, but failed.

```
    <div class="side-container">
        <!-- left side -->
        <aside>
        Left: Fixed width, 100% height of the window or right hand content
        </aside>

        <!-- main content -->
        <article>
        Right: Fluid width                       
        </article>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3AxY/7/

Here's my code
http://jsfiddle.net/sw8s4/
Any suggestions how to do this?

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/t3AxY/8/ ?

Comment: Please could you be more specific with your question ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
#content {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
#intro {
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    padding-right:40px;
}
#manned-flight {
    width: 100%;
}
article img {
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
}
```

I am not sure what exactly your output should look like, but this way you get two columns.
where the forst one gets a fixed width, and the second one resizes to fill the rest of the parent.

updatet your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw8s4/1/)

Now you can also put `height:100%;` on `body`, `#content` and `#intro` to make it 100% of the window height.